# Can a matrix be translated by a diagonal matrix to obtain a singular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Let $A$ and $D$ be $k \times k$ matrices with entries in the nonnegative real numbers $\mathbb{R}_+$, where $D$ is diagonal.

Does there exist a scalar $\lambda \ge 0$ such that $\det(A - \lambda D) = 0$?

Comment: That is too general. $D$ may be zero and $A$ invertible.

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume $\det(D) > 0$, as otherwise the statement is not true in general.

Notice that for the symmetric root $R = D^{1/2}$ we have
$$ \det(A - \lambda D) = \det(R)\det(R^{-1} A R^{-1} - \lambda I_n) \det(R). $$
Now, the function $\det(R^{-1} A R^{-1} - \lambda I_n)$ has a non-negative zero if and only if $M = R^{-1} A R^{-1}$ has a non-negative eigenvalue.

*If $A$ is symmetric:*

The matrix $M$ has a non-negative eigenvalue if and only if $M$ is not negative definite. Since $R^{-1}$ is invertible, that is exactly the case if $A$ is not negative definite. Since $A$ is component wise non-negative, $A$ can't be negative definite, as the diagonal elements would negative otherwise. Thus, we obtain following result:

> Let $A,D$ be square, component wise non-negative, matrices.
>   Assume $A,D$ are symmetric and $D$ is positive definite.
>   Then, there exists a $\lambda\ge 0$ with $\det(A - \lambda D)=0$.

*If $A$ is not symmetric:*

That case is little complicated.

In case $n$ is odd, if $\det(A) \ge 0$, then for $\lambda\to\infty$ we have 
$$ \det(A-\lambda D) = -\lambda^n \det(D - A/\lambda) \to -\infty. $$

In case $n$ is even, if $\det(A) \le 0$, then  $\lambda\to\infty$ we have 
$$ \det(A-\lambda D) = \lambda^n \det(D - A/\lambda) \to \infty. $$

So in these two cases, $\det(A-\lambda D)$ has a non-negative zero.

Comment: In the second case where $n$ is even, $\det A < 0$ and $\det D > 0$, why does $\det(A - \lambda D) \to \infty$ as $\lambda \to \infty$ imply that $\det(A - \lambda D)$ has a zero?

Comment: In the first case where $n$ is odd, $\det A , \det D >0$, is it possible that the zero is negative?

Comment: @ColinTan: 1. comment: the continuous function $f(\lambda) = \det(A-\lambda D)$ has a sign of $[0,\infty)$. 2. comment: consider $A = D = I_n$ then, $\det(A-\lambda D) = 0$ if and only if $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: @ColinTan: I have posted a better and complete answer.

Comment: Great answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$\det(A-\lambda D)$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$ of degree $k$.

Comment: Does $\det(A - \lambda D)$ have a nonnegative real root?

Comment: @ColinTan Not neccesarily, no. You can take $A=[1]$ and $D=[-1]$ to get $\det(A-\lambda D) = 1 + \lambda$ which has no nonnegative real roots.

Comment: There are a couple of points in the Question that limit the effect of this hint.  First $D$ is of *nonnegative* entries but not necessarily known to be nonzero, and obviously if it were zero, then we would not have a polynomial of degree $k$, and indeed there are other ways that might fail.  A more subtle difficulty is checking if a root $\lambda$ of the polynomial, should it have degree $k$, is nonnegative.  Consider $D$ the identity and $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$